# Show that $((0,1], \mathcal{B}_{(0,1]},U)$ is a non-atomic probability space

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $U$ be the Lebesgue measure on $(0,1],$ that is, $U(F) = \sum_{k=1}^n b_k-a_k$ where $F = \bigcup_{k=1}^n (a_k,b_k]$ and $0<a_1<b_1<a_2<b_2<\cdots b_n\leq 1$ with $n<\infty.$

The following question is taken from [Amir Dembo Probability theory 's lecture note.](https://statweb.stanford.edu/~adembo/stat-310b/lnotes.pdf), page $12.$

> Show that $((0,1], \mathcal{B}_{(0,1]},U)$ is a non-atomic probability space and deduce that $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B},\lambda)$ is a non-atomic measure space.

A probability space $((0,1], \mathcal{B}_{(0,1]},U)$ is non-atomic if for any $A\in \mathcal{B}_{(0,1]},$ if $U(A)>0$, then there exists $B\in \mathcal{B}_{(0,1]}$ such that $0<U(B)<U(A).$

Whenever I tried to solve for all Borel sets, I would consider another set and try to show that it forms a $\sigma$-algebra that contains open sets. 
However, in this case, if we defined 
$$\{A\in \mathcal{B}_{(0,1]}: U(A)>0\quad\text{and}\quad \exists B\subseteq A, 0<U(B)<U(A)\}.$$
It does not look like a $\sigma$-algebra.

Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $U(A) >0$ then $x \to U((0,x) \cap A)$ is a continuous function  which tends to $0$ as $x \to 0$ and $U(A)$ as $x \to 1$. Hence it attains all values in $(0,U(A))$. In particular there exists $x$ such that $U(B)=\frac {U(A)} 2$ where $B=(0,x)\cap A$. The proof for Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb  R$ is similar.

Continuity of $x \to U((0,x) \cap A)$ follows from the fact that $|U(0,a) \cap A)-U((0,b) \cap A)| \leq U(a,b)=b-a$ for $a <b$.

Comment: Perhaps you can justify the inequality $|U(0,a) \cap A)-U((0,b) \cap A)| \leq U(a,b)$ from definition of $U$?

Comment: It is basically a consequence of additivity of the measure. In fact for any measure $\mu$ we have $|\mu(C)-\mu(B)| =\mu (C \Delta B) $ where $C \Delta B$ is the symmetric difference between $C$ and $B$. When $C=(0,a)\cap A)$ and $B=(0,b)\cap A)$ we see that $C \Delta B$ is  subset of $(a,b)$.  @Idonknow

Comment: If $\mu(C) > \mu(B)$, then $|\mu(C) - \mu(B)| = \mu(C) - \mu(B) = [\mu(C\cap B^c) + \mu(C\cap B) ] - [\mu(B\cap C^c) + \mu(C\cap B)] = \mu(C\cap B^c) - \mu(B\cap C^c).$ How to conclude that it is equal to $\mu(C \Delta B)?$

Comment: @Idonknow $\mu (C)=\mu (C\setminus B) +\mu (C \cap B)$. Similarly, $\mu (B)=\mu (B\setminus C) +\mu (B \cap C)$. Now take the difference and use the elementary inequality $|a-b| \leq a+b$ for $a,b \geq 0$. .

Comment: So you are saying that $\mu(C\setminus B) - \mu(B\setminus C) = \mu(C\Delta B)?$ But I thought $\mu(C\Delta B) = \mu(C\setminus B) + \mu(B\setminus C)$ instead of difference...

Comment: @Idonknow Edited my last comment.